# PowerPoint: Border around some text in textbox

Tags: textbox, powerpoint

I have a textbox with a bunch of text in it in PowerPoint. How do I only put a border around one of the sentences?

This is what I want:

[image: textbox]

I made the above in Word, but even copy/pasting it into PowerPoint doesn't work. It copies the text, but not the border.

I'm using PowerPoint 2013.

Comment: Do you want to do this in VBA or some other language or ???   If via code, how will you decide what to put the border around?

Comment: No, just in the designer. Like in Word I can just highlight the text I want to put the border around and click the borders button in the home tab under paragraph.

Comment: In that case, you're better off asking the question in SuperUser, one of StackOverflow's "sibling" forums.  StackOverflow is for programming questions.  That said, the answer is really that you can't do this w/o a bit of VBA or other coding, other than by very tedious manual methods or by freehand drawing the rectangle you want.  If you want to have a go with VBA, I've got a page on the PPT FAQ with some code that you could mod:  Highlight text in PowerPoint
http://www.pptfaq.com/FAQ00776_Highlight_text_in_PowerPoint.htm

Comment: Ah, thanks, didn't know About SuperUser. We ended up just doing the freehand rectangle.